# Trying to use Laravel HTTP to upload a file to a 3rd party

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following Postman request for testing a third party API;

[image]

What I am trying to do is convert this into code using Laravel's HTTP class, the code i currently have is;

```php
public function uploadToThridParty()
{
    $uploadContents = [
        'id' => 'this-is-my-id',
        'fileUpload' => true,
        'frontfile' => Storage::get('somefrontfile.jpg'),
        'sideview' => Storage::get('itsasideview.png'),
    ];

    $request = Http::withHeaders(
        [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
        ]
    );

    $response = $request
        ->asForm()
        ->post(
            'https://urltoupload.com/upload', $uploadContents
        )
}
```

But every time I run this, the 3rd party API comes back with `Invalid ID`, even though if i use Postman with the same ID it works fine.

I cant seem to figure out where i am going wrong with my code;

Comment: `Storage::get` returns the file content as a string, I doubt the request class knows that it supposed to perform an actual file upload (instead of just sending a string value), based on that. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#multi-part-requests

Comment: @CBroe ... Can i send multiple files and still keep the structure that Postman is wanting? ... Sorry, im a bit new to this

Comment: You should be able to just call the `attach` method multiple times, I think. `$response = Http::attach(...)::attach(...)->post(...);`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? On dumping `$uploadContents`, do you receive the exact same values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Cbroe mention about attach file before sending post request you can make this like this example:

```
public function uploadToThridParty()
{
    $uploadContents = [
        'id' => 'this-is-my-id',
        'fileUpload' => true
    ];

    $request = Http::withHeaders(
        [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
        ]
    );

    $response = $request
        ->attach(
        'frontfile', file_get_contents(storage_path('somefrontfile.jpg')), 'somefrontfile.jpg' 
         )
        ->attach(
        'sideview', file_get_contents(storage_path('itsasideview.png')), 'itsasideview.jpg' 
         )
        ->post(
            'https://urltoupload.com/upload', $uploadContents
        )
}
```

Also i think you need remove asForm method because it's override your header accept type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded that is way your exception is Invalid ID

Comment: Do you mean i should change the 'Accept' from application/json to application/x-ww-form-urlencoded?

Comment: Not. you don't use asForm method

Answer (score 1):

Some third party API would require you to have the request with content type as `multipart/form data`

you can double check all the headers being pass on your postman request HEADERS tab and view on Hidden headers.

If you indeed need your request to be in multipart/form-data, You can use the `multipart` options of [guzzle](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#multipart).

Although this doesnt seem to be on [Laravel HTTP-Client docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client), you can simply pass a `asMultipart()` method in your HTTP request

just check the `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Http.php` for full reference of HTTP client.

You can have your request like this.

```
public function uploadToThridParty() {
    $uploadContents = [            
        [
            'name' => 'id',
            'contents' => 'this-is-my-id'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'fileUpload',
            'contents' => true
        ],
        [ 
            'name' => 'frontfile', 
            'contents' => fopen( Storage::path( 'somefrontfile.jpg' ), 'r') 
        ], 
        [ 
            'name' => 'sideview', 
            'contents' => fopen( Storage::path( 'itsasideview.jpg' ), 'r') 
        ], 
    ];

    $request = Http::withHeaders(['Accept' => 'application/json']);

    $response = $request->asMultipart()->post('https://urltoupload.com/upload', $uploadContents );
}
```